# how to log downloaded files

Tags: 7, hooks, files

I have a content type with a (private) file field. Content is protected by a node access module.

I would like to log (in a particular way) when a user is about to download a file.

[hook_file_download](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7) looks like it will do the trick, but on the other hand, its stated purpose is to "control access". I'm letting Drupal Core control access; I just want to log a (successful) download.

Is there a better hook to do this with?

Comment: there isn't a D7 version out there, but http://drupal.org/project/filefield_stats is a great module for D6, and maybe some of its code could be of use to you if you are already writing a module...

Comment: yeah, good tip, thanks. Basically that module makes a page callback function to deal with it. Had hoped there was a more graceful way to compliment the D7 private/'managed' files API

Comment: Just by the way, for public files it could be easily done at webserver level. Sadly won't work for private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_file_download()` is invoked in two occasions:

- When Drupal is verifying the users have access to the file they are trying to download

  ```
  function file_download_access($uri) {
    return count(file_download_headers($uri)) > 0;
  }
  ```
- When Drupal is returning the headers for the file to download (and then the data for the file to download)

  ```
  function file_download() {
    // Merge remainder of arguments from GET['q'], into relative file path.
    $args = func_get_args();
    $scheme = array_shift($args);
    $target = implode('/', $args);
    $uri = $scheme . '://' . $target;
    if (file_stream_wrapper_valid_scheme($scheme) && file_exists($uri)) {
      $headers = file_download_headers($uri);
      if (count($headers)) {
        file_transfer($uri, $headers);
      }
      drupal_access_denied();
    }
    else {
      drupal_not_found();
    }
    drupal_exit();
  }
  ```

In both the cases, the function invoking the hook is [`file_download_headers()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_download_headers/7).

```
function file_download_headers($uri) {
  // Let other modules provide headers and control access to the file.
  // module_invoke_all() uses array_merge_recursive() which merges header
  // values into a new array. To avoid that and allow modules to override
  // headers instead, use array_merge() to merge the returned arrays.
  $headers = array();
  foreach (module_implements('file_download') as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_file_download';
    $result = $function($uri);
    if ($result == -1) {
      // Throw away the headers received so far.
      $headers = array();
      break;
    }
    if (isset($result) && is_array($result)) {
      $headers = array_merge($headers, $result);
    }
  }
  return $headers;
}
```

Watching the Drupal code, I cannot assure the hook is always called twice in row, during the same page request; if it were so, you could take the necessary action when the hook is invoked for the second time.

I would rather change the callbacks for `$directory_path . '/styles/%image_style'` (where `$directory_path` contains the value returned from `file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme('public')->getDirectoryPath()`), system/files/styles/%image_style, system/files, and system/temporary to verify when a file is going to be downloaded, and log what happening.

This is not going to change in Drupal 8, as it doesn't split `hook_file_download()` in two hooks.